# add the selected item from a ComboBox to the DefaultListModel

Tags: java, eclipse, combobox, jlist

i have a combobox that displays items at a restaurant, i want to be able to select the item then click a button below that will add it to a DefultListModel, i have managed to do this but i have to use many if statements

```
if(comboBoxStarters.getSelectedItem() == "Sticky Chicken Wings") {
    selectedItems.addElement("Sticky Chicken Wings");
}

if (comboBoxStarters.getSelectedItem() == "French Onion Soup") {
    selectedItems.addElement("French Onion Soup");
}

if (comboBoxStarters.getSelectedItem() == "Bacon and Salmon Brochettes") {
    selectedItems.addElement("Bacon and Salmon Brochettes");
}
if (comboBoxStarters.getSelectedItem() == "Sesame Chicken Skewers") {
    selectedItems.addElement("Sesame Chicken Skewers");
}
```

i know you can do this in just a couple of lines of code but i cant remember how, i have this so far:

```
selectedItems.addElement(this.comboBoxStarters.getSelectedItem());
itemList.setModel(selectedItems);
```

but this isnt compiling

(selectedItems is my DefaultListModel)
(itemList is my Jlist)

also all the code above is inside a button action event listener

Comment: What's the compile error?

Comment: it is not about your question but don't use `==` for string comparison, make your comparisons like that

      `if(comboBoxStarters.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Sticky Chicken Wings"))`

Answer (score 0):

Cast the getSelectedItem() return value

```
selectedItems.addElement((String)this.comboBoxStarters.getSelectedItem()); // added (String) cast
itemList.setModel(selectedItems);
```

Answer (score 0):

`this` may still be referring to your `ActionEventListener`; you might need to use a "qualified this" to refer to your outer class's `this` pointer, like `OuterClassName.this`.

`getSelectedItem()` can return `null` if no item is selected, so it is wise to first check if it is non-null.

```
Object selected = OuterClassName.this.comboBoxStarters.getSelectedItem();
if (selected != null) {
    selectedItems.addElement((String) selected);
    itemList.setModel(selectedItems);
}
```

Even safer would be `if (selected instanceof String) {`, unless you are completely sure your combo box will only contains strings.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are using Java 7 or an upper version. In java 7 DefaultListModel definition is like that

```
DefaultListModel<E> model = new DefaultListModel<E>
```

So you must cast the selected item to E

```
selectedItems.addElement((E) this.comboBoxStarters.getSelectedItem());
```

And of course `getSelectedItem()` should return an object with type E.